# How to structure Spring Cloud Gateway, Keycloak and React js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a microservice application powered by Spring Boot in the backend and React Js in the front. I am using Spring Cloud Gateway to proxy requests to downstream services and standalone Keycloak to secure requests.

I have two architectures in my mind.

**Option 1**
Using SCG as OAuth 2.0 client to request tokens from Keycloak and relay the token to downstream services.

**Option 2**
Using the react app as OAuth 2.0 client and SCG as OAuth 2.0 resource server to validate the token using Keycloak and authenticate requests.

I know there is no one answer to this question but I want to know what are the best options from the above 2 options with their possible pros and cons.

Any sugesstions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is following a pattern called **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend and has two main advantages over the second:

- it is hiding OAuth2 tokens from Javascript code
- it allows to use confidential OAuth2 clients (Javascript frameworks can't keep a secret)

Requests between the frontend (your React app) and the BFF are secured with:

- sessions cookie which can be hidden from JS code (should be flagged `Secure`, `HttpOnly` and `SameSite`)
- CSRF cookie with `HttpOnly=false` for your React app to read it and return its value as `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header (should be `Secure` and its value rotated frequently to prevent BREACH attacks)

I wrote [a tutorial for this on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).